# I can't calculate the address of a pointer with LD operation in the LC-3 simulator

Tags: assembly, machine-code, lc3

Program code below:

```
0011 000 000000000    ;Start at 0x3000
0101 010 010 1 00000  ;R2 <- 0 (counter)
0010 011 000010000    ;R3 <- M[x3012] (ptr)
1111 0000 00100011    ;Input to R0 (TRAP x23)
0110 001 011 000000   ;R1 <- M[R3]
0001 100 001 1 11100  ;R4 <- R1 <- 4 (EOT)
0000 010 000001000    ;if Z, goto x300E
1001 001 001 111111   ;R1 <- NOT R1
0001 001 001 1 00001  ;R1 <- R1 + 1
0001 001 001 0 00 000 ;R1 <- R1 + R0
0000 101 000000001    ;If N or P, goto x300B
0001 010 010 1 00001  ;R2 <- R2 + 1
0001 011 011 1 00001  ;R3 <- R3 + 1
0110 001 011 000000   ;R1 <- M[R3]
0000 111 111110110    ;Goto x3004
0010 000 000000100    ;R0 <- M[x3013]
0001 000 000 0 00 010 ;R0 <- R0 + R2
1111 0000 00100001    ;Print R0 (TRAP x21)
1111 0000 00100101    ;HALT (TRAP x25)
                      ;Starting Address of File
0000 000 000110000    ;ASCII x30 ('0')
```

The problem that I have begins at string 3 - R3 <- M[x3012] (ptr). I can't understand how the pointer gets the address x3012. I know what is the address because of the LC-3 simulator. It shows that. And how is PCoffset9 computed?

Comment: `PCoffset9` is a 9 bit offset to the current program counter. Since your code starts at `x3000` that instruction is at `x3002`. You can see the offset in the instruction is `x10` in binary. Hence the full address is `x3002 + x10 = x3012`

Comment: What @Jester said, except, the instruction in  question is at `0x3001`, though the pc value that this `LD` instruction uses is pc-next (so target is still `0x3012`): "An address is computed by sign-extending bits [8:0] to 16 bits and adding this value to the ***incremented PC***. The contents of memory at this address are loaded into DR. The condition codes are set, based on whether the value loaded is negative, zero, or positive."  For an instruction at 0x3001, the incremented PC is 0x3002

Comment: So, I refreshed the code to simplify the value of PCoffset, just for example. It has 1010 in binary (10 in decimal) now. And then instruction LD starts to load the content of the address x300C into the register R3. That means PCoffset (value of 1010) + PC (1) = 11. Am I correct?